# ASP.NET List not saving to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am having trouble getting this list to save to the database, I have stepped through the code and everything executes but the changes are not saved to the database.

This is the list in the model, this is also where I am initializing it:

```
public List<Event> BandEvents { get; set; }

public Band()
{
    BandEvents = new List<Event>();
}
```

This is the controller method where I am saving the data:

```
db.Bands.Find(BandID).BandEvents.Add(@event);
db.SaveChanges();
```

After the `db.SaveChanges()` has been executed I ran the following code in my immediate window: `db.Bands.Find(9).BandEvents.ToList();` , and I can see the item has been added to the list but this is not saving and when I try to pull the list elsewhere it is empty.

Comment: You don't have enough here for an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you defined mapping for Event type in EF and relations with Band?

Comment: Can you share how are you constructing @event object and its structure too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define relationship between those types. Have a look at [Configure One-to-Many Relationship](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx).